# MATLAB Edit Focus and Cursor Placement

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am using the `uicontrol` command to have focus on my edit object. After this command, the string inside the `uicontrol` is selected. How can I place the cursor after the last character ?

Here is my code.

```
H = figure;
E1 = uicontrol( 'Parent', H, 'Style', 'Edit', 'String', 'ABC', 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.1,0,0.1,0.1] );
T1 = uicontrol( 'Parent', H, 'Style', 'Text', 'String', 'ABC', 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.2,0,0.1,0.1] );
uicontrol( E1 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting to do cannot be realized through pure Matlab code. You have to interact with the underlying Java components... and for this you require the non built-in function [findjobj](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects).

Here is an example:

```
len = numel(E1.String);
jEdit = findjobj(E1);

uicontrol(E1);
jEdit.setCaretPosition(len);
jEdit.setSelectionStart(len);
jEdit.setSelectionEnd(len);
```

Comment: The cursor is correctly placed but the whole content of the uicontrol is also selected, how can I deselect it ?

Comment: jEdit.setSelectionStart(len) jEdit.setSelectionEnd(len)